# Type String is not a subtype of type int of index.I'm trying to parse Json String Array to object list. What is wrong?

Tags: rest, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get data from an API. When I receive the response in my model class, console shows an error like this

```dart
E/flutter ( 9292): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

Model Produit.dart:

```dart
/*My model*/
class Produit {
    String designation;
    double prixvente;
    double prix_vente2;
    String description;
    String image;
    int idProduit;

    Produit(this.designation, this.prixvente, this.prix_vente2,
        this.description, this.image, this.idProduit);
    /*fromJson, deserialization of json*/

    static Produit fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
       return Produit(
       map['designation'],
       map['prixvente'],
       map['prix_vente2'],
       map['description'],
       map['image'],
       map['idProduit'], );
    }
}
```

Usage getProduit async :

```dart
// Api
Future<List<Produit>> getProduit() async {
   try {
       var data = await http.get("http://" + Uri.encodeFull(url),
         headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
       this.produits = [] ; /* Lis<Produit> produits */
       List<Produit> items = [];
       print(prodsJson[0]);
       prodsJson.forEach((item) {
          items.add(Produit.fromMap(item));
       });
       print(items);
       this.produits = items ;
       return products;
   } catch(e) {
       print('Error ${e.toString()}');
   }
}
```

Mon Widget FutureBuilder:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getProduit(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.data != null ? Text(snapshot.data)
              : Center(child:  CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        },
      ),
    //bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomBar(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getProduit();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Json :

```
[
  [" GLITTER UP BRUSH - PINCEAUX MAQUILLAGE", 25000, 25000, " GLITTER UP BRUSH - PINCEAUX MAQUILLAGE", null, "1"],
  [" IF THE CROWN FITS - PINCEAUX MAQUILLAGE", 20000, 20000, " IF THE CROWN FITS - PINCEAUX MAQUILLAGE", null, "2"]
]
```

Comment: Your json seems to be an array of arrays but not an array of maps. So `static Produit fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) ` method needs to do something like `static Produit fromJson(List items)` then `items[0], items[1] etc.`